# Using variables as paths for images in react native

Tags: javascript, android, image, react-native

### **My Goal**

I am trying to create an app with react native, and want to have an image that can change depending on the circumstances. I want to have a list of paths, and then select the image by choosing an item in the list.

### **What I have tried**

I have tried making an image that looks like this:

```js
<Image source={require(icons[iconNum])} />
```

But whenever I try that, I get an error saying,

```js
Requiring unkown module "./images/exampleImage.png".
```

I have also tried using a single variable, that isn't a list, and that gives me the same error. How could I use a variable to select the correct image that I want to use?

Comment: instead of putting the string path in the array, why don't you put the whole object, `require("./your/image/path")` on the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is a javascript keyword with a **preload** nature, you have to prepare every resources you want to use, simply create a resources file for that. ex:

```
export var icons = [
  require('./icon/icon1.png'),
  require('./icon/icon2.png'),
  require('./icon/icon3.png'),
  ...
];
```

Images are pre-bundled into App, provide related path at runtime doesn't mean anything.

You can easily prove it by changing `require("./icons/icon.png")` to `require("./icons/"+"icon.png")`. Although they are logically the same, latter one will never works.